# Changing one data frame also changes it's copy

Tags: python, pandas

Couldnt come up with a better title, so here we are. I am running the following code:

```
dow_23457 = df
dow_23457 = dow_23457.set_index('date', inplace = True)
dow_23457 = dof_2345i.shift(24)
dow_23457 = dow_23457.reset_index()
```

As far as I understand, I first make a copy of 'df' and then I change the copy. What makes me confused is that when I run the second line, the 'date' column, becomes the index even in the 'df' data frame. The changes from the two following lines, only applies to the copied (dow_23457) data frame though. How can this happen?

Comment: direct reassignment creates a view, not a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I first make a copy of 'df' and then I change the copy

Nope! When you do `dow_23457 = df`, you're making `dow_23457` *look* at the same underlying object `df` has been looking at. Direct assignment doesn't copy data in the language.

You need to be explicit:

```py
dow_23457 = df.copy()
```

which makes `dow_23457` now look at an entirely different, newly made dataframe object which is independent of what `df` looks at. (well except you had some lists, dicts etc. in the cells of the dataframe, which resists in the copying process... but you shouldn't have them in the cells of a dataframe in the first place!)

---

For more on this "naming" subject, you might want to see [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1/names1.html#1) (it has also a video form as well as plain text).

Comment: Just curious: why do you say you shouldn't have lists or dictionaries inside DataFrames? I find it quite useful to be able to put basically anything inside a DataFrame, because DataFrames allow highly convenient slicing for further processing.

Comment: uh, then you lose the benefit of "vectorized" operations on the frame, e.g., thinking about adding two columns together where they both have list-valued; `+` operation will concatanate them! and there's no way to element-wise add them in a speedy manner. You need to explode-sum-groupby-agg_back, or a list comprehension.... Shortly, pandas data structures are not tailored to contain lists, dicts (strings are fine!). After all, a Series and/or DataFrame *itself* is a list-like and a dict-like structure! @StephanT

Comment: Sure, but not all applications of a DataFrame _need_ vector operations. And as programmer you know the purpose and limitations of the DataFrames that you yourself create. So it doesn't seem like a fundamental objection, just a context-dependent choice.